# echo a sql query inside a JQuery function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have a column in MySQL database there has the column "published". That column as a tinyint, where `0 = false` and `1 = true`. Basically I need to convert true or false into yes or no.

I echo my information out with the below script. Everything is working except the `var query statement`. I tried to make the query as a variable, and then use the variable in my modal-body, But then I get nothing printet out at all.

How can I use a sql query inside of my modal-body?

**UPDATED CODE**

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-open-modal").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'getdata.php', //Fetch records 
      data: {
        post_id: id
        var query = "SELECT (CASE WHEN video <> 0 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END) As Value";
      }, //That's how you send data throught Ajax
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var jdata = JSON.parse(data);
        if (jdata) {
          console.log("is json");
          $("#editBox").modal().show();
          $("#editBox .modal-title").html(jdata.headline);
          $("#editBox .modal-body").html("Weekday: " + jdata.weekday + "<br><br>Description: " + jdata.description + " " + query); // $query => query

        } else {
          console.log("not valid json: " + data);
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `data :  'post_id='+ id, //Pass $id` that's not how you send data with Ajax. `$_POST['post_id=1']`, why would you want to do that this way?

Comment: `var query = "SELECT ...` do you mean you try executing a PHP query inside JS with jQuery ?

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I thought I could do that, but apparently I am on the wrong track then. I need to print out if the value is true or false. The only way as I see it, is to check for 0 or 1 in the column. I need to echo that out in my modalbox, that is why I thought I had to have the sql query in my JQuery. Is there a suggestion how else I should do that?

Comment: I would `1) execute PHP query -> get the needed ID in a var` and then `2) prepare jQuery and <?php echo"$id"; ?>` where needed in function

Comment: You just want to show the string in 'query' in the modal-body element? Then just remove the '$' before the 'query'  where you append

Comment: Of course you can submit an SQL query to PHP. However, in most cases this is not what you want. In rare cases you might want it, e.g. when developing another phpMyAdmin. Usually you have all the SQL in your PHP script and the client does not know anything about the data structure. You would only accept values binding them to prepared statements for security reasons.

Comment: @manian: No I would also like to get the data there is in the column :-)

So the conclusion is study some more appartly before I will try to program this.

Comment: Consider, when I visit your site, I could manipulate the request to submit an SQL string like `DROP DATABASE ...`

Comment: It is just a small home project, where I wanted to practice on excact this function. I have prepared statements for my insert etc. But this question was more if and how I could call the sql statement, so I got the output in my modalbox with yes or no

Comment: So just put the `query` as a property into the `data` object of the ajax call extending Oen44's answer below. Then read it in PHP from `$_POST` array and send it to the DB.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I just updated my qestion my the new code. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Mimi :  what is the purpose of this snippet ? launch a video in a modal ? Get the id / status of the video then show it ?

Comment: @OldPadawan. Basically the purpose is to practice to print out strings, int, tinyint in a modalbox. It is just to get my hands dirty in the code. I have a button which have the function of showing me 3 randoms id's from the database. Each id have a button "Select". When I hit the select button, the modalbox is showing, and print out the columns that belongs to that id. All that is working, but it is the true/false I cannot figure out how to make.

Comment: @Mimi :  so PHP gives you 3 random IDs, then you have 3 buttons, each one linked to a video ID ? If so, with jQuery, just get the selected ID (on click), and launch modal with the selected ID (if I properly undestood what you mean to achieve...)

Comment: Thank you for your time. Yes all that is working as it should. The only thing there is not working is how I print `var query = "SELECT (CASE WHEN published <> 0 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END) As Value";` in my `$("#editBox .modal-body").html(query);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a mess... Use this.

```
var query = "SELECT (CASE WHEN published <> 0 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END) As Value"; // Well, ok.
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-open-modal").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'getdata.php', //Fetch records 
      data: {
        post_id: id
      }, //That's how you send data throught Ajax
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var jdata = JSON.parse(data);
        if (jdata) {
          console.log("is json");
          $("#editBox").modal().show();
          $("#editBox .modal-title").html(jdata.headline);
          $("#editBox .modal-body").html("Weekday: " + jdata.weekday + "<br><br>Description: " + jdata.description + " " + query); // $query => query

        } else {
          console.log("not valid json: " + data);
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```